# Obtener registros y mostrarlos en un Select

Tags: php, mvc, html-select

Buen día, quisiera saber cómo puedo mostrar los registros obtenidos en un Select en HTML, actualmente me encuentro usando el modelo Vista-Controlador en PHP, pero no me puedo imaginar cómo implementar los resultados obtenidos del modelo directamente en la vista.
Les explico: Estoy trabajando con usuarios y roles, por lo que, por ejemplo, un usuario de rol "user", tiene forzosamente un tutor de rol "admin", por lo que, obtengo de esta manera los usuarios con el rol admin y los guardo en una variable.

**Modelo**

```
   public function obtenerTutores()
{
    try {
        $query = $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE rol = "admin"');
        $query->execute();
        if ($query->rowCount() == 1) { //Si la consulta es exitosa, obtengo el registro del campo y lo guardo en la variable 
            $resultado = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (isset($resultado['nombre'])) {
                error_log('SignUpUsuarioModel::Success -> Nombre de tutor encontrado');
            }
        } else {
            error_log('SignUpUsuarioModel::Error -> Tutor no encontrado');
        }
        return $resultado;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Lo que hace este modelo es, en teoría obtener el nombre de todos los tutores encontrados, y guardarlos en la variable, ahora bien, no sé cómo hacer para mostrarlos en el Select que se encuentra en la vista...
Sé que tengo que pasarlo al controlador, pero, no habrá una manera de enviarla directamente a la vista?

**Controlador:**

```
        function MostrarTutores(){
    $tutores = $this->model->obtenerTutores();
    }
```

**Vista**

```
                                <div class="col-lg-12 my-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="custom-select" name="tutor" id="tutor" required>
                                        <option selected>Tutor asignado...</option>
                                        <?php 
                                        foreach ($resultado as $option) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $option['nombre'] ?>"><?php echo $option['nombre'] ?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Pero así como lo tengo no funciona nada :p, bueno, espero me puedan aconsejar y bien, dar solución, muchas gracias

Comment: En el  estilo MVC la manera que existe es pasando los datos del Controlador a la Vista. ¿Por qué quieres hacerlo de otra forma?

Comment: @A.Cedano porque no sé cómo podría implementarlo desde el controlador :( por eso pido ayuda

Comment: Aunque hay varias formas de hacerlo, y en algunos casos se usan plantillas y demás, [mira este ejemplo simple](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/)  que te dará un idea de hacerlo. Repito: no es es el único estilo que existe.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me he guiado un poco de ese artículo y he podido resolver el problema, saludos!! :D